# Synchronizing two render passes: color attachment to sampled?

Tags: vulkan

In Vulkan, suppose I have two render passes:

1. the first outputs to an image as its color attachment.
2. the second samples from that same image from its fragment shaders (ie through a combined image sampler).

The render passes are submitted in that order.

What's the correct way to synchronize these two render passes so the second doesn't read before the first has written?

It is necessary and/or sufficient to create an image pipeline barrier on the image in between them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is necessary and sufficient to have an image memory barrier between them:

1. Execution barrier: You need to ensure the second renderpass fragment shaders (`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`) don't start executing before all of the first renderpass color attachment writes (`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT`) complete.
2. Memory barrier: You need to ensure the first renderpass color attachment writes (`VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT`) are *available* and *visible* to the second renderpass image sampling instructions (`VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT`) .
3. Layout transition: You need to change the layout of the image from `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL` to `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`.

All of those can be done in a `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` with a single `VkImageMemoryBarrier`. Or you can use a `VkSubpassDependency` on one of the two renderpasses (with `dstSubpass` or `srcSubpass` set to `VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL`) and the attachment's `oldLayout` and `newLayout` fields.